# How to send information from the far side of the Moon to the Earth?

Tags: the-moon, communication

Chang-E has just sent a shot after landing on the far side of the moon. It looks tricky, how  can a device send information from a place that is oriented opposed to Earth?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a satellite that has a view of the landing site and the Earth. There are several possibilities for doing this. According to the [NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraft/display.action?id=QUEQIAO), the communications are relayed through the satellite Queqiao which is in a halo orbit around the Earth-Moon L<sub>2</sub> point.

You could also have a satellite in lunar orbit, transmit data from the lander while it's over the far side, transmit data to Earth while it's over the near side.

Or relay via a satellite in interplanetary space, etc.

Comment: I've just added a bounty to [Was Queqiao in a halo or Lissajous orbit? Why do sources disagree?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45920/12102)